# The last number in a matrix is wrong

Tags: c, matrix

I'm new at programming and I'm trying to do some exercises in C.
When I put 2 in all matrix slots the last returns 5 instead 4.

[The last one was supposed to be 4 but appears as 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enyOz.png)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int al,ac,bl,bc,cl,cc;
    int matrizA[5][3], matrizB[5][3], matrizC[5][3];

    for ( al=1; al<6; al++ )
        for ( ac=1; ac<4; ac++ )
        {
            printf("MatrizA [%d] [%d] = ", al, ac);
            scanf("%d", &matrizA[al][ac]);
        }
    for ( bl=1; bl<6; bl++ )
        for ( bc=1; bc<4; bc++ )
        {
            printf("MatrizB [%d] [%d] = ", bl, bc);
            scanf("%d", &matrizB[bl][bc]);
        }
    for ( cl=1; cl<6; cl++ )
        for ( cc=1; cc<4; cc++ )
        {
            matrizC[cl][cc]=matrizA[cl][cc]+matrizB[cl][cc];
        }
    printf("MatrizC= \n [%d] [%d] [%d]\n [%d] [%d] [%d]\n [%d] [%d] [%d]\n [%d] [%d] [%d]\n [%d] [%d] [%d]", matrizC[1][1], matrizC[1][2], matrizC[1][3], matrizC[2][1], matrizC[2][2], matrizC[2][3], matrizC[3][1], matrizC[3][2], matrizC[3][3], matrizC[4][1], matrizC[4][2], matrizC[4][3], matrizC[5][1], matrizC[5][2], matrizC[5][3]);
    return(0);
}
```

Any thoughts?
Thanks :)

Comment: In C, array indices start at 0, not 1.  Thus, the valid indices for an array of 5 elements are 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4, but NOT 5.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post text as text.

Comment: Flip to the section in your book/tutorial on how zero-based indexing works. Your overrunning array boundaries literally *everywhere* in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array indexing in C is `0` based.  You are starting with `1`, and ending with `n` in all of your array assignments.  You should be starting with `0` and ending with `n-1`.

For example, in this code section your array is defined to contain [5][3] elements, which should be accessed using indexes [0-4][0-2].  But you are accessing using [1-5][1-3].
By writing beyond the memory your array owns, you are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

```
int matrizA[5][3], matrizB[5][3], matrizC[5][3];
for ( al=1; al<6; al++ )
    for ( ac=1; ac<4; ac++ )
...
```

Change this (and other similar sections) to use the correct array indexing:

```
int matrizA[5][3], matrizB[5][3], matrizC[5][3];
for ( al=0; al<5; al++ )
    for ( ac=0; ac<3; ac++ )
...
```